# Parsing json response using play libs

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0

I need to parse json response in a play application and get all the fields/values in a list.

I'm getting the response as below:

```
WSRequestHolder request = WS.url("someurl");
request.setQueryParameter("somekey", "somevalue");
Promise<Response> promise = request.get();
Response response = promise.get();
JsonNode json = response.asJson();
```

The response comes like below:

```
{"results":{"key1":value1,"key2":value2,"key3":value3},"errorMessage":"","statusCode":2000,"success":true,"version":"1.01"}
```

I need to get all the feilds/values from "results" list. How can i do this using play json libraries / apis available? I'm using play 2.1.1.

Thanks.

Comment: The official documentation explains how to do this: 
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJsonRequests

Answer (score 0):

Since the result is a `JsonNode`, you have all the niceties of `JsonNode` available to you.

For instance, if you want to access `"results"`, do:

```
JsonNode results = json.get("results");
```

You also have methods such as `.has()`, `.path()`, `.entries()`, etc etc. One `JsonNode` can represent any JSON value, including `null`.

To test the type you can use the `.is*()` methods: `.isObject()`, `.isNumber()`, `.isMissing()` (note: the latter requires the use of `.path()` instead of `.get()`).

Example:

```
json.path("foo").isMissing(); // true
json.path("errorMessage").getTextValue(); // ""
json.get("results").get("key2"); // value2
json.get("success").getBooleanValue(); // true
```

Etc etc. See [the javadoc for `JsonNode`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html).

Another solution would be to deserialize that JSON into a POJO. But that means creating the POJO in the first place, and then use an `ObjectMapper` to `.read*()` the value.

(side note: it is surprising that Play uses Jackson 1.9.x whereas 2.0+ has been available for many years...)